# Analysis of partially correlated data, possible with LMEM?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

I have an analysis problem I'm trying to solve, but I think I have too limited of a stats vocabulary to describe it, so I'm struggling to find papers to read. I was hoping to explain it here and get some guidance on where I should be investigating (though more specific advice is more than welcome). Here it is:

Let's say I have 30 subjects in an experiment. They all contribute two data points, one from a different part of their body (let's say "dexterity" from each hand on a continuous measure). Each hand has been independently categorized (on an entirely different measure) as a "healthy" or an "unhealthy" hand. Some people will have two healthy hands, other two unhealthy, some one of each.

So, I want to test the hypothesis that hand-health effects dexterity, but control for the fact that some people contributed a hand to one group (people with two hands of the same health), while others contributed to both groups (people with two hands of different health). This is important because dexterity is correlated between the hands.

Is there a name for this kind of (quite inconvenient) data structure? How would I test the hypothesis >without< throwing away data (we have done this before, and I don't like it). I could just do two separate tests, but this will reduce power. Can I analyze this with a linear mixed effects model, and would this require some custom correlation matrix?

Here's an illustration of the issue:

[image: hand-health comparison]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Bayesian Hierarchcial model. Hierarchical because your data are nested within individuals. The model can be defined as follows:

$$y_{i} \sim \text{N}(\mu_{h[i],p[i]}, \sigma^2)$$

where $y$ is the target variable (e.g. dexterity), $\mu_{h[i] = 1,p[i]}$ is the effect of healthy hand, and $\mu_{h[i] = 2,p[i]}$ is the effect of unhealthy hand for person $p[i]$ on his/her target variable. Then we assume there is an effect for healthy hand and another effect for unhealthy hand in the population and person specific effects are drawn from the distribution of the population effects like below:

$$\mu_{h[i],p[i]} \sim \text{N}(\mu_{healthy[i]}, \sigma^2_{healthy[i]})$$

$\mu_{healthy[i]}$, and $\sigma^2_{healthy[i]}$ are the parameters of the population distribution that we are interested in. Note that $healthy[i]$ can take two values 1 and 2 associcated with healthy and unhealthy hand respectively. So we will have two different population distribution associated with each condition.

And finally we need to specify some hyperpriors on the parameters. Since each person has only two person and the number of individuals are only 30, you better choose informative priors distributions. For this toy example I simply chose the below priors:

$$\mu_{healthy} \sim \text{N}(7, 3^2)$$
$$\sigma_{healthy} \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 5)$$

Now let's fit the model in R using R2jags package:

```
# ----- Simulating some data -----
healthy = 10 # Average effect in the population for healthy hand
unhealthy = 5 # dito dito unhealthy hand

df = data.frame()
x = c()
set.seed(123)
for (j in 1:30){ #loop over individuals
  for (i in 1:2){ #loop over hands
    x[1] = rnorm(1, healthy, sample(1:3,1))
    x[2] = rnorm(1, unhealthy, sample(1:3,1))
    z = sample(1:2,2, replace = T)
    y = x[z]
    id = rep(j,2)
    df_temp = data.frame(y = y, id = id, health = z)
  }
  df = rbind(df, df_temp)
}


# ------------------ JAGS full model --------------------
library(R2jags)

mod_string = " model {
  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    # Likelihood
    y[i] ~ dnorm(health[type[i], person[i]], tau) # tau = 1/sigma     
  }
  
  # ------- hierarchical priors -------
  
  for (i in 1:max(person)) {
  
    health[1,i] ~ dnorm(mu_pop_health[1], sigma_pop_health[1]^-2) 
    health[2,i] ~ dnorm(mu_pop_health[2], sigma_pop_health[2]^-2) 

  }
  
  # --- hyper priors ------
  
  for (j in 1:2){
    mu_pop_health[j] ~ dnorm(7,3^-2)
    sigma_pop_health[j] ~ dunif(0,5)
  }
  tau ~ dgamma(1.0E-3, 1.0E-3)

} "

data_jags = list(y = df$y, 
             type = df$health,
                 person = df$id
)

params = c('mu_pop_health')

set.seed(123)
# Run the model
model_run <- jags(
  data = data_jags,
  parameters.to.save = params,
  model.file = textConnection(mod_string)
)

print(model_run)
```

And here are the results:

```
> print(model_run)
Inference for Bugs model at "8", fit using jags,
 3 chains, each with 2000 iterations (first 1000 discarded)
 n.sims = 3000 iterations saved
                   mu.vect sd.vect      2.5%       25%       50%       75%     97.5%  Rhat n.eff
mu_pop_health[1]     9.413   0.248     8.923     9.242     9.415     9.579     9.889 1.001  2700
mu_pop_health[2]     5.029   0.269     4.504     4.845     5.025     5.210     5.562 1.001  3000
```

In the above table, *mu.vect* gives the average values of the target variable in the population associated with 1 = healthy and 2 = unhealthy hands. As you can see, the model accurately estimated the average effect associated with each condition for a hand and it also gives the 95% credible interval for its estimates.